# SciPy Windows install: f.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, pip, python-3.6

I installed Python 3.6 on my Windows 64 bit machine (I already had Python 2.7 installed on it) I tried to `pip3 install seaborn` but `scipy` is a dependecy. I thought I had it installed but apparently I do not.

I downloaded the corresponding wheel file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy): `scipy‑0.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`. But when running `pip3 install`scipy‑0.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` I am getting the error:

```
scipy‑0.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

This problem has happened to many other people, but none of the solutions I've read had helped me:

- I made sure I am trying to install the correct version: Python 3.6 and 64-bit. Actually I downloaded and installed the wheel file for `seaborn` successfully, but that's not good enough because I still need `scipy`.
- I have tried upgrading `pip` with `pip3 install --upgrade pip` but the most recent version was already installed.

What can I do other than installing Anaconda and having to set up again my Python 3 environment again? (and I wouldn't even be positive that this will work with Anaconda)

Comment: Anaconda works... (just mentioning it because of your last sentence). And show some output of calling your python3.6 in the console.

Comment: @sascha I did copy the command I am running with `pip3` to install the wheel file. And `pip3` is located at: `(whereis pip3) C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip3.exe`.

Comment: Run it, the .exe (what's unclear about *show some output of calling your python3.6 in the console*?)

Comment: Ah nevermind. Your last comment gives it away. Read that path **Carefully**! **Hint:** 32...

Comment: When I type `py -3` (there is no other keyword like `python3`) the Python 3.6 interactive console shows up. Same when I execute `pyhon.exe` in the aforementioned location.

Comment: Oh god damn it... How do I even have Python 3 32-bit installed on my machine in the first place? I'm dumb.

Comment: Actually I do remember the reason now: to have Python 3 in jupyter notebook (Python 2.7) I had to install Python 3 32-bit, the 64-bit version didn't work on the 2.7 notebook.

Comment: Now it's your decision if going from scratch or using the 32-bit builds. I don't like 32-bit much :-) **And to be honest:** anaconda is much easier to use (also for your problem in the last comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(whereis pip3) C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scr‌​ipts\pip3.exe`

Either you renamed your folder (low probability), or your install is Python 3.6 in it's **32-bit version!**

You are trying to install a 64-bit version (`scipy‑0.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`), therefore `is not a supported wheel on this platform`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem. Managed to install `seaborn`, obviously cue a new issue: `DLL load failed` when importing `seaborn`...

Comment: That's a problem with numpy/scipy install (99% sure; somehow incompatible; seaborn does not have any low-level dll components as far as i know). There is a reason anaconda is that popular :-)

Comment: I just installed that wheel file, downloaded straight from that site. What could have gone in the installation? I did not see anything suspicious in the process, and I actually just uninstalled `scipy` and `seaborn` and installed them again and same issue.

Comment: Those wheels are hard to manage (i did not use them for a long time). Not much advice to give except for a completely clean install (incl. numpy) or using an alternative.

Comment: Right... I should probably uninstall everything and just go with Anaconda. It does include jupyter notebooks right? I hope it's easy to use my existing notebook projects with the new installation.

Comment: Sure it does. The only possible problem: if your existing notebooks are very old; well... let's see. Multiple possible problems there (e.g. changes in pandas...). But one should go for recent versions of those libs, even if one has to port old code somehow.